# Multiple Header Tokens Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http

In my API i have a before_filter for restrict_access

```
        def restrict_access
            authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
                ApiKey.exists?(access_token: token)
            end             
        end
```

and in the header it places a token (from php wordpress plugin)

```
'header'=>'Authorization: Token token="' . $my_access_token . '"'
```

Can I send multiple tokens to the header? Like an access token for the model they are accessing and an identity token for who is asking for it?  If so how do you have it check for two different tokens?

Answer (score 0):

You can make one large token saving all the information and then cut it in the rails app and get the information you need.

Or you can get the token manually doing something like this:

```
def authenticate
  token = request.headers['custom-auth-token']
  ApiKey.exists?(access_token: token)
end
```